# Qgis: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, qgis

I Try to make plugin in qgis and I have a problem.
when I put code into python console under plugins this works:

```
  def Style_for_layer():
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()[0]
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point and layer.name() in ["one","two"]:
         layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Users/user/Desktop/style_one.qml')
    elif layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line and layer.name() == "some name layer":
  layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Users/user/Desktop/style_two.qml')
    else:
            pass
    legend = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface()
    legend.itemAdded.connect(Style_for_layer)
```

the other side when i maked plugin by "plugin buildier" this not work:

```
  def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        # show the dialog
        #self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        #result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        #if result:
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()[0]
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point and layer.name() in ["one","two"]:
            layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Users/user/Desktop/style_one.qml')
    elif layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line and layer.name() == "some name layer":
            layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Users/user/Desktop/style_two.qml')
    else:
        pass      
    legend = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface() 
    legend.itemAdded.connect(run)
```

then when i try use plugin:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why in console it works but not working in plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Just look for what return `qgis.utils.iface.legentInterface().layers()`.

If you are in a plugin, this is not the way to access to iface, since it is passed as an argument at the initialization of the plugin.

Anyway, `legendInterface` is deprecated, and you should use the layer registry to do this.

`QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()` will return a dictionary of all layers or `mapLayer(my_layer_id)` will return the proper layer.